# Laravel add extra buttons in nav bar if user is logged in

Tags: laravel

I want to add/change some buttons of nav bar while user login to the website. How can I do that.
for example before user login to the website I have login button in navbar but while user logged in to the system login should be replaced by logout.
I made custom authentication system.

I used session for login.

```
 public function loginUser(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'voterId'=>'required', 
        'password'=>'required',
    ]);
    $user = User::where('voterId','=',$request->voterId)->first();
    if($user){
            if(FacadesHash::check($request->password, $user->password)){
                
                $request->session()->put('loginId', $user->id);
                return redirect('dashboard');
            }
            else{
                return back()->with('fail','Incorrect password');

            }
    }
    else{
        return back()->with('fail','This voter Id is not registered');
    }
}
```

Comment: do you keep a login token for each user in your database. in other words, how do you determine if your user is logged in? A flag? A token in database? Session?

Comment: you can use `@auth` blade directive to show links only when user is logged in. Will however only work if you use Lravel to log the user in.

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#authentication-directives. Even with a "custom authentication system", it _should_ still be using Laravel's authentication logic in some form, so the `@auth` directive (or offshoots) should still work. If they don't, then please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72940326/edit) and include more details, including your custom authentication implementation and any associated errors.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you are using laravel default Auth and user model for your project. For that, use:

```
@if (Auth::check())
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="login()">Login</button>
@else
  <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
@endif
```

If you are not using default auth method for laravel, then you need to specify how your login and logout system is handled for me to give you a better answer.